# C++ WTSQueryUserToken Function Error

Tags: c++, token

I'm trying to get my service to create a process as a user, but I have to get the token first. Now for some reason, My function keeps returning error 87, which is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. Anyone know why? It's been bugging me for hours, the parameters are correct from what I see. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
PHANDLE currentToken = 0;
ULONG id = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    printf("ULONG = %d", id);
// Get token of the logged in user by the active session ID
BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(id, currentToken);
if (bRet == false)
{
    printf("ERROR: %d", GetLastError());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue as follows:
defined currentToken as a HANDLE rather than a pointer (PHANDLE) and passed a reference to it to the WTSQueryUserToken function

```
PHANDLE currentToken = 0; 
changes to:
HANDLE currentToken = 0;
```

And...

```
BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(id, currentToken);
//Change this to:
BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(id, &currentToken);
```

After this I got a 1314 - ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD error but that was because the application needs to be running as user "localsystem" and the only way to do that is to run it as a service - out of scope for this answer, I resolved the 87 error anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` is not returning a valid session id? Try `WTSEnumerateSessions` to get the active session:

```
    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &dwCount);

    int dataSize = sizeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO);

    // look over obtained list in search of the active session
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i)
    {
        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = pSessionInfo[i];
        if (WTSActive == si.State)
        {
        // If the current session is active – store its ID
            dwSessionId = si.SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get token of the logged in user by the active session ID
    BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, currentToken);
```

[Source and full code example found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11167/).

Comment: See I tried this but Enumeratesesions just gives me an error that it cannot establish an RFC server. Started thinking it might not be possible on Win7 due to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7trainingcourse_sessionisolation_unit.aspx

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem as there are several RDS permissions that you need to have to enumerate sessions, [see this document link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383488(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I am also in the same position - using enurmate sessions produces the correct session id (1 - verified by using tasklist at the command prompt where I can see my session ID against applications I am running) However, with identical code to above, its giving me error 87 back.